# Get files in firebase storage without directories

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

How to get files in firebase storage from directory without directory itself?

```
const getFilesOptions = {
    directory: "example/",
}

defaultBucket.getFiles(getFilesOptions).then(function(getFilesResponse) {
    const filesArr = getFilesResponse[0]
})
```

With this code filesArr will contain all the files and directories like example/..., including example/ directory itself. Is it possible to exclude this directory from results? Or maybe to exclude any directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see in the [documentation for `GetFilesOptions`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/global.html#GetFilesOptions), there is no option to exclude the current directory from the results.

You could *try* using the `prefix` option with a trailing `/`, to see if that excludes the directory itself. But I'd expect that to include the directory itself too, in which case you'll have to filter it out of the results yourself in your application code.

Comment: Yes, trailing / has no effect at all

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that. As said, in that case your only option seems to be to filter the directory in your own code.